# Disable anchor links WITHOUT javascript

Tags: asp.net, html

Let's pretend this works:

```
<a href="target.html" enabled="<%# myboolean %>">Zelda</a>
```

Okay, but it doesn't. What is the closest I can get to this setup? I basically want the text to either be a link or to be regular text depending on `myboolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `if` statement in your `asp.net` code if you really want to switch between a link and just plain text.

```
<% if (myboolean) { %>
  <a href="target.html">Zelda</a>
<% } else { %>
  Zelda
<%} %>
```

Comment: hot damn I did not know you could do that.

Comment: `<p>Zelda</p>` is not plain text; it is a word marked up as a paragraph (causing display as a block with margins above and under by default). Use just `Zelda` or `<a>Zelda</a>`.

Comment: Updated to better match the question.  Thanks Jukka!

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the element using:

```
<a href="target.html" <%# myboolen ? "style=\"display:none;\"" : "" %>>Zelda</a>
```

**OR** disable the element's onlclick

```
<a href="target.html" <%# myboolen ? "onclick=\"javascript:return false;\"" : "" %>>Zelda</a>
```

**OR** you could disabled the element's onlclick by making the tag runat server and use the code behind

*Front End*

```
<a href="target.html" runat="server" id="anchor">Zelda</a>
```

*Code Behind* (you would have to do this within your bind event by the looks of it)

```
anchor.attributes.add("onclick", "javascript:return false;");
```

Whichever you think is tidiest :)

Comment: This would also accomplish what I need. Thanks for the response

Comment: Both answers were top notch, but this one is closest to the original question, so you get bronus points. They're like bonus points but they work out more

Comment: The `disabled` attribute is invalid in `a` and not recognized by browsers, except IE. Ditto for `readonly`, except that even IE ignores it.

Comment: Ah, I did not know as I did not get a chance to test it yet.

Comment: In that case, instead of the disabled & readonly combo, you could add this `onclick="javascript:return false;"` instead. You'll basically get the disabled anchor this way :P